# Window CryptoAPI: Can I choose the public exponent when generating an RSA key pair?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, cryptoapi, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Using the Windows CryptoAPI, is there any way to specify which public exponent to use when generating a new key-pair (ie. 3 instead of 65537)?

As a bonus question: how would I access this functionality using .NET `RSACryptoServiceProvider`?

**EDIT:** My guess is that the answer is "No", but I would like to get confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - there we go :) More seriously [CryptGenKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379941%28VS.85%29.aspx) The only parameters you can send to CryptGenKey are set in [CryptSetKeyParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380272%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can see from the documentation you can only set a limited number of properties for each key type, and only one for RSA keys.

(Plus, as I'm sure you're aware, small exponents are dangerous anyway)

Comment: Prime? Generator? If you are talking about KP_G and KP_P, those are for DSA.

Comment: Errr doh. Slows how asleep I am :)

Still, the parameters structure still applies, it's the only way to effect key generation, and there's nothing there for RSA except for KP_OAEP_PARAMS

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers your second question:

[EncryptTo/DecryptTo: Encryption in .NET with CryptoAPI Certificate Stores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867080.aspx)